# How to sync bookmarks across Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sync, bookmarks

How to sync bookmarks across Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox bookmarks?

As I currently understand, Google Chrome puts bookmarks separately from Google Bookmarks, which is accessible in Firefox by using Google Toolbar for Firefox. Right?

So, how should I synchronize my browsers? I use Google Chrome as my primary browser.  It works good and bookmarks are synchronized across a number of computers I'm using.

Comment: After being unable to disable Chrome tabs feature on my Android device (even after changing its flags! Chrome on Android is a total mess and badly broken IMO!) I've decided to use Firefox on Android and keep using Chrome on my desktop. But now I have this ridiculous data syncing problem. Thanks for asking this, currently(in 2021) EverSync seems to work fine for me. But I'm not sure, I should see how things will go in a few days/weeks/months.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, as jcnaquin suggested, [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is awesome.

([Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla), [Firefox Ad-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/))

Not only can you do cross-browser, but you can set up profiles for different computers (Work/Home/Custom) and determine which bookmarks/folders go with each profile. This can help you choose if you want specific bookmarks to be at home, or if you want to leave them at work.

In addition, you can sync Passwords, or Open Tabs on each computer, but only if you want to, of course.

Comment: As a common sense, make sure to turn off bookmarks sync in both Chrome & Firefox on all machines prior to using Xmarks. It is truly a nightmare when all three bookmarks sync service are fighting, duplicating exponentially bookmarks across 14+ browsers among 6 or 7 boxes.

Comment: @Antony can confirm. Do not leave bookmark sync turned on in Chrome Sync. Bad things will happen

Comment: not yet compatible with firefox quantum

Comment: Xmarks is now planned to be discontinued, so EverSync may be the best alternative currently.

Answer (score 15):

Give Xmarks a try. http://www.xmarks.com/

Comment: Does it sync history too?

Comment: I used to use Xmarks, but it was sometimes hogging CPU to the point it was more of a hindrance than a help, so I got rid of it.

Comment: xmarks will discontinue...

Answer (score 7):

There is no actual way to sync your bookmarks through different web browsers without using one of those services (like [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com), [EverSync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/fvd-synchronizer/) or Delicious, for example) that require you to create an account. The problem with that is that it might lead your browser to create several copies of your bookmarks, making a REAL mess, as Antony said.

Of those 3, I personally recommend EverSync, as you can freely use it on your phone as well, but there are many more similar services, most of them with the same multisyncing issue.

Answer (score 6):

There has been a tentative project to implement Weave Sync into Google Chrome
http://code.google.com/p/chromeweave/

as well as https://bitbucket.org/philikon/weaveclient-chromium

Comment: Unfortunately the last update still seems to be from Feb 24, 2011

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it without the use of any add-ons by using the following steps:

1. Go to "Show all Bookmarks" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
2. Click on "Import and Backup"
3. Select "Import data from other browsers"
4. Select the browser from which you want to import the bookmarks and click **Next**
5. All the bookmarks are imported under the folder as "From Google Chrome" so one does not have to worry of the same name folder or same bookmarks present in it.
6. Now you can manually organise the new bookmarks according to your need.

Comment: This is just one time import of bookmarks. So it is not what is expected.

Comment: This doesn't sync.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [Delicious](http://delicious.com/).

It syncs between IE, Chrome and Firefox.

I believe it can synchronize with dropbox as well.

Comment: Where on the delicious site do you get this tool?

Comment: You will need to sign up.

Comment: yes delecious is just awesome, works best for all mainstream browsers, apart from it here is a good list of tools that you can use apart from Xmarks 

http://www.programmerfish.com/top-3-ways-for-syncing-bookmarks-between-different-browsersexcluding-x-marks/

Comment: +1 for suggesting Delicious, its quite nice bookmarking tool/service

Answer (score 0):

I am using Firefox Sync because I use Firefox as my primary browser, but Firefox Sync completely messes up my bookmarks, creating duplicates each time I log on to one of my computer. Seems to work only for a single-computer setup, which is quite outdated nowadays.

Xmarks has been discontinued since months. Last time I tried it because the website came back online I don't know why, the server wasn't responding at all.

Manually importing bookmarks works, AGAIN, for a single-computer setup. But I will never always think about saving my bookmarks when I leave one computer, copy that somewhere (e.g., Dropbox), and restoring when logging on another computer.

It seems that the only way is now to bypass the browser's bookmarks and setup a web server with an HTML page with links, and update the page manually to add bookmarks, or get rid of all computers except one in order to use some bookmark-syncing options above.

Comment: The webserver solution does not actually require a webserver, though. Just create a simple html-file and open it in your browser, possibly synced through Dropbox or SpiderOak.